# How to find the relative density of a solid soluble in water?

Tags: density

I know what is relative density and how to find it, but what I can't understand is how do I find relative density of something soluble in water like salt?

Since, relative density is with respect to density of water, if I replace the water with some other liquid in which it is insoluble, then how do I get the relative density of the solid(since I replaced water itself)?

A worked out derivation of something would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The 'trick' here is to assume the dissolution of solute into solvent brings about **no changes to the solvent's volume $V_S$ and no  changes to the solute's volume $V_t$**. For the most part this a very reasonable assumption.

Assume the relative densities (to water) to be $d_s^1$:

$$d_s^1=\frac{m_s}{V_s}$$

And $d_t^1$:

$$d_t^1=\frac{m_t}{V_t}$$

For a mixture containing $m_s$ of $1$ and $m_t$ of $2$:

$$m_s=d_s^2\times V_s$$
$$m_t=d_t^2\times V_t$$

The final density $d_{solution}^1$ is:

$$\boxed{d_{solution}^1=\frac{d_s^1\times V_s+d_s^1\times V_t}{V_s+V_t}}$$